# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace' while trying to remove '/n'

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributeerror

I've got a bunch of files that I need to rename. I've got the names in order in a text file and I need to remove the linebreaks that are inserted when reading the text file, but I keep getting this error.  *AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace' while trying to remove '/n'*

Any and all help is appreciated, I really don't know what I'm doing.

```
from os import rename, listdir


fnames = listdir('.')
file = open("names.txt", "r")
namelist = [line.split(' ') for line in file.readlines()]
namelist = [n.replace('\n', '') for n in namelist]

print (namelist)
```

Comment: where are you using `fnames` other than declaration?

Comment: do you want a flat list as the final result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that after `split` each `n` in `namelist` already is a *list* of strings.

If you want to remove the newlines at the end of the lines, you can either reverse the two comprehensions, to first `remove` and then `split`, or just combine them into one. Also, instead of `replace`, you can use `strip` to get rid of the newline character at the end of the line.

```
namelist = [line.strip().split(' ') for line in file]
```

Comment: Good idea with the `strip()`. It is more elegant and more pythonic than replacing newline character with space, which depending on the operating system might not always be just `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

`.readlines()` returns a list of lines, each ending with a `\n`. There's no point to expect it anywhere else (provided that you use universal newlines when reading the file: mode `"r"`, not `"rb"`).

The whole thing can be made a whole lot shorter is you just iterate over the file (it yields lines, too):

```
namelist = []
for line in input_file:  
    namelist.extend(line.rstrip('\n').split(' '))
```

As a fun exercise, it can be made a one-liner (a bit less efficient):

```
namelist = sum((line.rstrip('\n').split(' ') for line in file), [])
```